# Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen »Atem« und »Atmung«?

Tags: difference

Die Übersetzungen dieser Nomen in meine Muttersprache sind ganz gleich. Gibt es eigentlich einen Unterschied zwischen ihnen?

---

Wenn ich mich nicht irre, sind die Antworten von Jan und von Hubert gleich, troztdem habe ich die Antwort von Jan akzeptiert, weil er früher als Hubert geantwortet hat. Vielen Dank euch für Antworten!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Atmung** is the derived noun from the verb *atmen* referring to the process of breathing.

> Seine Atmung ist schwach (his breathing is weak)
>   Fische sowie einige Lurche betreiben Kiemenatmung (Fish and some amphibians use gill breathing)

The second sentence is slightly constructed and probably wouldn't be said that way. A better way would be to say:

> Fische und einige Lurche atmen mit Kiemen (Fish and some amphibians breathe with gills)

The first sentence can also be rewritten with *atmen*:

> Er atmet schwach (he is breathing weakly)

Which further shows the connection of *Atmung* (breathing) to *atmen* (to breathe)

**Atem**, on the other hand, refers to the air that is breathed.

> Gott hauchte Adam seinen Atem ein (God breathed life into Adam, literally God breathed his breath into Adam)
>   Die Atemluft besteht zu circa 20 % aus Sauerstoff (the air one breathes is made up of approximately 20 % oxygen).
>   Mit seinem Atem konnte der Riese ganze Wälder vernichten (With one breath of air the giant could destroy entire forests).

These sentences can't be turned into a verbalised form with *atmen* (at least not trivially), because the meaning is not directly connected to the verb.

Comment: Warum formulierst du die Antwort in einer Fremdsprache wenn der Fragesteller sie doch auf deutsch gestellt hat? Melkogotto hat zwar angegeben eine andere Muttersprache als Deutsch zu haben, aber er/sie hat mit keiner Silbe zu verstehen gegeben, welche Muttersprache er/sie spricht. Möglicherweise versteht Melkogotto gar kein Englisch. Da er/sie in seinem/ihrem Profil auch keinerlei Angaben gemacht hat, wissen wir nur, dass er/sie gut genug Deutsch spricht um eine Frage in korrektem Deutsch zu formulieren. Über die Kenntnis anderer Sprachen (inkl. Englisch) wissen wir nichts.

Comment: Wenn auch nicht in der Frage enthalten könntest du noch das Atmen mit aufnehmen,  das einen Bezug zur Atmung hat.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast hat recht, ich entschuldige mich, dass ich keine Informationen über meine Sprachkenntnisse gegeben habe. Zum Glück verstehe ich Englisch gut.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Weil ich, ehrlich gesagt, gar nicht drüber nachgedacht habe, und automatisch auf Englisch angefangen habe. Jetzt steht für mich die Frage im Raum, ob ich sie lieber übersetzen sollte, oder ob sie so stehenlassen soll?

Comment: @Melkogotto auch an dich noch einmal die Entschuldigung, dass ich aus mir unbekannten Gründen einfach auf Englisch geantwortet habe, ohne mir zu überlegen, warum du auf deutsch fragst, und ob ich besser auf deutsch auch geantwortet hätte.

Comment: Nein, ich glaube übersetzen ist nicht notwendig. Aber du bist leider nicht der einzige, der hier in einem *Deutsch*-Forum lieber auf Englisch statt auf Deutsch schreibt.

Answer (score 1):

Die beiden Begriffe kann man von zwei Enden des Spektrums kommend betrachten.

1. **Atmung**
   Ist der medizinisch-technische Begriff, der den physiologischen Prozess des Luftholens mit seinen Parametern wie Intensität, Geschwindigkeit und Frequenz betrachtet. "Atmung" ist viel enger im Anwendungsbereich als "Atem"
2. **Atem**
   Hat einen wesentliche weiteren Bedeutungsumfang, manchmal fast metaphysisch, in der Betrachtung des Gesamtzustands eines Menschen. Atem kann auch im übertragenen Sinn benutzt werden oder einfach nur für den Vorgang des Luftholens.

Und dann gibt es einen Überschneidungsbereich, in dem je nach Blickwinkel beide Begriffe Sinn machen.

Comment: Kommt mir beides unrichtig vor, aber ich tu mich schwer es zu begründen. Atmung ist m.E. kein Prozess - vielleicht eine Funktion. Und Atem ist kein Vorgang, sondern die Luft, die geatmet wird. Außerdem ist mir ein Rätsel, von welchem Spektrum die Rede ist und was dessen Enden auszeichnet.

Comment: Spektrum: "Atem" vom esoterisch angehauchten Sinne ("Lebensatem", "atmet den Geist von XYZ") bis ganz pragmatisch wie "der Atem beschlägt die Scheibe". Atmung ist immer ganz wörtlich, nicht übertragen. Zumindest fällt mir beim besten Willen kein Gegenbeispiel ein.

Comment: Also was den Prozess betrifft rudere ich zurück, das scheint mir doch eine angemessene Vokabel. Spektrum jedoch nicht. Die Sprache ist mehr wie ein Garten, hier steht was, da drüben steht was, dort steht was anderes, aber es gibt kein lineares Ordnungsprinzip wie im Lichtspektrum das von Rot bis Blau reicht mit definierten Richtungen auf denen man etwas einsortieren kann. Jedenfalls heißt der Vorgang des Luftholens nicht der Atem, sondern das Atmen.

Answer (score 1):

### Atmung

Das ist ein Vorgang, der meist wie folgt verstanden wird:
Die Muskulatur des Brustkorbs und das Zwerchfell vergrößern und verkleinern in einem sich ständig wiederholenden Zyklus das Volumen der Lunge, wodurch Luft durch die Luftröhre ausgepresst (ausgeatmet) und eingesaugt (eingeatmet) wird. Diese muskuläre Tätigkeit, und auch das Ein- und Ausströmen der Luft werden als *Atmung* bezeichnet.

Darüber hinaus kann *Atmung* auch den Gasaustausch bedeuten, der nicht nur in der Lunge von Lungenatmern, sondern auch in den Kiemen und Tracheen anderer Tiere stattfindet. Sogar der Gasaustausch, der an den Blättern von Pflanzen stattfindet, wird gelegentlich als Atmung bezeichnet.

Und nicht zuletzt ist *Atmung* auch ein Stoffwechselvorgang, bei dem energietragende Moleküle mit Hilfe von Sauerstoff oxidiert werden, um die gespeicherte Energie freizusetzen. (Dabei entstehen typischerweise die energiearmen Verbindungen Wasser und Kohlendioxid.)

Die Tätigkeit, die durch das Wort *Atmung* beschrieben wird, kann durch das Verb *atmen* umschrieben werden, wobei das aber bei der Beschreibung des Stoffwechselvorgangs unüblich ist. Man kann sogar Schuhe kaufen, die nach Angabe des Herstellers atmen. Das bedeutet nichts anderes, als dass zwischen dem Innenraum des Schuhs und der Außenseite ein Gasaustausch stattfinden kann.

### Atem

Das ist die Luft, die man ein- oder ausatmet. Die eingeatmete Luft spendet Leben, die ausgeatmete Luft ist verbraucht. Aus diesem Grund wird in vielen Kulturen dem Atem (nicht jedoch der Atmung) eine mystische Bedeutung beigemessen. Das berühmteste Beispiel stammt aus den großen monotheistischen Religionen (Judentum, Christen und Moslems): Gott formte einen Menschen (Adam) aus Lehm, und erweckte ihn dadurch zum Leben, dass er ihm durch die Nase seinen Atem einhauchte. Das, was Adam also zum Leben erweckt hat, war die ausgeatmete Luft eines Gottes, also dessen Atem.

Daraus leitet sich auch der Glaube ab, die Seele eines Sterbenden würde mit dessen letztem Atem den Körper verlassen. Um einen Teil der Seele eines geliebten oder besonders geschätzten Menschen auch nach dessen Tod bei sich behalten zu können, wurde vielfach der letzte Atem eines Sterbenden in einem Behälter aufgefangen. So bewahrte z. B. der amerikanische Industrielle Henry Ford ein verschlossenes Reagenzglas auf, in dem ein Teil des letzten Atems des Erfinders Thomas A. Edison aufgefangen wurde.

Da mit »Atem« keine Tätigkeit, sondern ein Gegenstand (wenn auch gasförmig und somit ohne feste Form) gemeint ist, korrespondiert mit diesem Substantiv auch kein Verb. Das oben beschriebene Verb »atmen« steht nur mit dem Substantiv »Atmung« in einem sinnhaften Zusammenhang, nicht jedoch mit »Atem«. Gemeint ist, dass man einen Satz, in dem das Wort »Atmung« vorkommt, durch einen anderen Satz, in dem stattdessen das Wort »atmen« vorkommt, unter Beibehaltung des Sinns ersetzen kann. Bei einem Satz, in dem das Wort »Atem« vorkommt, geht das üblicherweise nicht.